# How to use comma in description using `glossaries`?

Tags: glossaries

How to use comma in name using `glossaries`?

```
\newglossaryentry{smth}
{
  name=somthing (s., smthg),
  description={description}
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your code to...

```
\newglossaryentry{smth}
{
  name={somthing (s., smthg)},
  description={description}
}
```

Include at the name={,,,,} ;)